# Stripe Custom Payment Form Implementation

Tags: javascript, php, html, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement payment module in my website using stripe gateway. But I did not use the build-in checkout form [With Elements (Stripe.js v3)] that stripe provides where stripe does all validation for us. Instead, I am trying to create a custom payment form. I have shared my code below.

Can anyone help me in validating the payment form I have created (Validation should be the same as what stripe does in build-in checkout form) and explain this also: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

With stripe.js v3 , we can customize payment form and its validation?

I like to validate name filed, postalcode field, email and card number and its corresponding CVV with client side code(js).

Comment: Where is the code that you have tried

Comment: Hi, I think you forgot to share your code :) 
Just a warning, if you are not using stripe provided Elements or checkout, you will be liable for PCI Compliance https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance which require you to provide more compliance documents

Answer (score 0):

I have Also Customise stripe elements. I think you should follow [This Stripe Elements Doc](https://stripe.dev/elements-examples/) For customize it.

It is also provide code of customised form in repositories.